# How HLS streaming using Cloudfront passes through CORS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, video.js

I am trying to implement HLS streaming using S3 + Cloud Front + Signed Cookie.

I set the viewer access limit to No as shown in the picture below. (The picture says Viwer Access limit in Korean).)

[image: set the viewer access limit to No]

Then, the video is normally played as follows. (CORS error does not occur.))

[image: video play]

However, the viewer access limit was set to Yes and key groups were also set.
Then, a CORS error occurs as follows.

[image: set the viewer access limit to YES]

[image: CORS error]

As far as I know, the viewer access restriction is a setting to inspect Cookie, and I wonder why CORS errors occur according to this setting.

When the viewer access limit is set to No, a CORS error does not occur, and when set to Yes, CORS occurs. What is the problem?
I'm sorry I can't attach the picture yet.

---

update 1:
Api calls are made at api.cledge.io.
Cloudfront has set the domain to vod.cledge.io.

I want to run vod.cledge.io/videos/y2mate.m3u8.

This is the S3 CORS setting.

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://cledge.io",
            "https://api.cledge.io",
            "http://localhost"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption",
            "x-amz-request-id",
            "x-amz-id-2"
        ]
    }
]
```

CloudFrontUtill.class

```
@Component
public class CloudFront {

    @Value("${cloudfront.domain}")
    private String domain;

    @Value("${cloudfront.key-id}")
    private String keyId;

    @Resource
    private CloudFrontConfig cloudFrontConfig;

    public void getSignedCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String resourcePath) throws Exception{
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        Date generateDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
        Date expireDate =  calendar.getTime();
        CloudFrontCookieSigner.CookiesForCustomPolicy cookies = CloudFrontCookieSigner.getCookiesForCustomPolicy(
                SignerUtils.Protocol.https,
                domain,
                cloudFrontConfig.getCloudFrontKeyFile(),
                resourcePath,
                keyId,
                expireDate,
                generateDate,
                "0.0.0.0/0"
        );

        Cookie policy = new Cookie(cookies.getPolicy().getKey(), cookies.getPolicy().getValue());
        policy.setDomain("cledge.io");
        Cookie signature = new Cookie(cookies.getSignature().getKey(), cookies.getSignature().getValue());
        signature.setDomain("cledge.io");
        Cookie keyPairId = new Cookie(cookies.getKeyPairId().getKey(), cookies.getKeyPairId().getValue());
        keyPairId.setDomain("cledge.io");
        response.addCookie(policy);
        response.addCookie(signature);
        response.addCookie(keyPairId);
    }

}
```

My Controller (api.cledge.io)

```
@Controller
public class VideoController {

    @Resource
    CloudFront cloudFront;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "https://vod.cledge.io")
    @GetMapping("/video")
    public String streamVideo(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        cloudFront.getSignedCookie(response, "videos/*");
        return "video";
    }
}
```

html code (video.js)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>lab.naminsik.com</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #video{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width=100% class="video-js" controls>

</video>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.2/video.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //document.cookie = "${policy}";
    //document.cookie = "${signature}";
    //document.cookie = "${keyPairId}";
    const options = {
        crossorigin: 'anonymous',
        cors: 'anonymous',
    }
    var player = videojs('video',options);

    player.src({
        src: 'https://vod.cledge.io/videos/y2mate.m3u8',
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
        withCredentials: true
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this yet?